# Prevent MariaDB from filling up tmpdir and hanging the system

Tags: mysql, mariadb

We're running MariaDB version 10. To speed up queries we have set up `tmpdir` to be RAMDISK with size of 35GB.

The challenge we have is that from time to time (like once or twice a week) MariaDB fills the `tmpdir`, after which the whole system freezes up till we have to stop MariaDB, unmount the `tmpdir` and remount.

Initially the `tmpdir` was 15GB we have been increasing it over time with hope that more space will prevent MariaDB filling up the `tmpdir` but we realize it's not ending. We could still expand `tmpdir` but we don't have unlimited RAM and are not sure how much will be enough.

At this time we're wondering whether there's a way to prevent MariaDB from filling up `tmpdir`? The alternative is to move `tmpdir` to disk but this is a route we're avoiding since it would present a performance nightmare.

```
open_files_limit=5000
query_cache_size = 0
wait_timeout=200
tmp_table_size=512M
max_heap_table_size=512M
thread_cache_size=64

key_buffer_size=256M
max_allowed_packet=512M

table_open_cache=10240
table_definition_cache=32768

delayed_insert_timeout=20 # Turn on if max_connections being reached due to delayed inserts
delayed_queue_size=300 # Turn on if max_connections being reached due to delayed inserts

myisam_sort_buffer_size=512M # can be increased per sessions if needed for alter tables (indexes, repair)

query_cache_limit=32M # leave at default unless there is a good reason
query_cache_type=1

read_rnd_buffer_size=16M # leave at default unless there is a good reason
read_buffer_size=2048M


collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
character_set_server=utf8

general_log=0
log-output=TABLE # select * from mysql.general_log order by event_time desc limit 10;

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_buffer_pool_size=16448M
innodb_log_buffer_size=100M
innodb_thread_concurrency=8 # Number of physical + virtual CPU's, preset when server is provisioned to have correct # of cores
innodb_change_buffering=all
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
innodb_support_xa=0
innodb_doublewrite = 0
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 2
```

Comment: Just use tmpfs and a big swap file. tmpfs goes to swap if memory is tight

Comment: MySQL/MariaDB mostly uses `tmpdir` for sorting if whatever it needs to sort does not fit in the allocated RAM, so "prevent it from filling up tmpdir" basically means "don't ask it to sort large row sets", which you achieve by optimizing your queries and adding appropriate indexes.

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ we have swap but it never used `tmpdir` fills up. Is there something we need to do to enable this?

Comment: Listen to @mustaccio though. If you're doing sorts that big you probably need to rethink some queries / design

Comment: @mustaccio all columns in which we perform sorting are indexed. 2ndly, we don't construct queries by hand. We use **Laravel** framework which we assume has querries optimized.

Comment: How regular are the times when tmpdir fills? The frequency could indicate one or two queries run periodically that are *not* well optimized, by the framework or by your server. If possible, it may be worth finding the processes that are consuming tmpdir as it gets close to the boundary, and seeing if a pattern starts to emerge.

Comment: Queries constructed by a persistence framework are unlikely to be optimized, and you may index columns all you want but the optimizer may choose not to use those indexes. Apply the usual query optimization techniques.

Comment: @MugomaJ.Okomba, no framework generates optimized queries other for very trivial cases. I assume the troublesome query is some kind of report, you should probably have a look at the query and see what it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

`tmp` is used when `mysql/mariadb` engine can't use `ENGINE=MEMORY` for temporary tables. That happens for many reasons:

- Temporary table is too big to fit into `join/sort` buffer. That may
  be caused by too small buffers or by queries that produce too big
  results due to the bad design.
- Temporary table contains text/blob fields that are not appropriate
  for MEMORY engine.
- Proper index(es) are missed for the query, so massive filesorts performed on the disk in the mysql/tmp dir.

Anyway as far as disk-based temp-tables are significantly slower than in-memory ones, queries that fill up the `mysql/tmp` dir are listed in the slow queries log along with short diagnosis.

Comment: We have checked slow queries log but nothing showing up. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/171353/find-queries-creating-disk-temporary-tables-on-mariadb-mysql. If we can tell which queries are hogging `tmpdir` it will be easy to be fix.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use RAM Disk.  It takes away from what MySQL would prefer to use RAM for -- the buffer_pool.

How much RAM do you have?  I see 16GB already in use for the buffer_pool, so I hope you have considerably more than that.

If a query is filling up /tmp, the *probably* it need to be looked at.  A typical problem that leads to such is this pattern:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(...)
    FROM t1
    JOIN t2 ON ...
    ...
    GROUP BY ...
```

I call it "explode-implode".  And usually the aggregate values are bot slow in coming and wrong.  And, as you are finding out, it takes a lot of disk space.

Please provide the naughty query, `EXPLAIN` of it, and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` of the relevant tables.

As for assuming that 3rd party software is well optimized; well, don't get me started.

Comment: We don't have queries doing `count` nor queries doing `group by` but we have a lot of queries doing `join`. As for RAM we have 48GB. What do you advice? We eliminate RAM disk and increase `buffer_pool`?

Comment: How much data do you have?  The buffer_pool should be no more than about 70% of RAM, but also does not need to be bigger than the total of data and indexes.  If you shrink it below the data+index (in order to make a ramdisk, then swapping one optimization for another.

Comment: Please show us the monster query that needs such a big RAM disk; apparently my guess was wrong.  Also provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Perhaps we can give suggestion(s) on how to make it less bulky.

Comment: Oh, another pattern that _may_ help in this situation:  "lazy eval".